# dotnet CLI builds and packs nuget differently to visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a .netstandard assembly project with the following csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;net462</TargetFrameworks>
    <VersionPrefix>1.0.2</VersionPrefix>
    <VersionSuffix>alpha</VersionSuffix>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="protobuf-net" Version="2.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I build this within visual studio the correct nuget package is created. Namely :

```
myassembly.1.0.2.alpha.nupkg
```

However, when I use the cli the values in VersionSuffix and VersionPrefix are ignored

```
dotnet build myassembly.csproj
```

produces

```
myassembly.1.0.0.nupkg
```

I am running .net core sdk 1.0.4
Visual Studio is up to date (15.2).

I need to be able to run the CLI on the CI server, but this is causing a lot of headaches. Is it a version problem somewhere?

Comment: Both `dotnet pack` and `dotnet build` produce the right `nupkg` for me with the project file you've shown there.

Comment: Is it possible that your CI server is overriding those values, or specifying Version explicitly?

Comment: To be honest I havent got as far as getting it on the CI server. I am running this as proof of concept on my development machine first. I am seeing the issue there.

Comment: That's very odd - as I say, it seems totally fine to me, with that exact project file.

Comment: I updated the CLI recently using the installer linked from here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd Could this be the issue?

Comment: Nope, I'm using that too. It would help if you'd show the output of `dotnet --info` from the project directory... and have you tried this with a fresh project, just a single no-op class?

Comment: .NET Command Line Tools (1.0.4)


 Product Information:

  Version:            1.0.4

  Commit SHA-1 hash:  af1e6684fd

 Runtime Environment:

  OS Name:     Windows

  OS Version:  6.1.7601

  OS Platform: Windows

  RID:         win7-x64

  Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4

Comment: I'll try with a new project shortly....

Comment: This also works for me and I have the same version/hash of the CLI tools, though my RID is win10-x64.

In CI systems I've worked on before I have just been setting the MSBuild property with the build command itself. That may or may be helpful depending on your desired setup though `dotnet build myassembly.csproj /p:VersionPrefix:1.2.3 /p:VersionSuffix=foobar`